# Getting row id in ag-grid for Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid to display a table, where one of the columns has a link.

Click the link will open a new page. To determine what page will be open, I need the row id (based on the row id, I'll put a condition). How can I get the row id in ag-grid for Angular 4?

2. In order to display html / links / etc. in a cell, their documentation says to do it through cellRenderer - to call a component.

My 2nd question is: when calling the component - is there a way to pass an input to the rendered component through Input? Is it possible?

Something like:

```
export class MyCustomCellRendererClass {
   @Input() a:any;
}

var colDef3 = {
cellRenderer: MyCustomCellRendererClass [a] = "a",
...
```

}

The component inside the cell (for example `MyCustomCellRendererClass`) needs to open a specific link, so in order to know which link, I need to pass a property from the table to `MyCustomCellRendererClass`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the `agInit` function in your `MyCustomCellRendererClass` class? The parameter passed to the `agInit` function is of type `ICellRendererParams`, and this contains information that you can use in the renderer. Just `console.log` the parameter to see what's there.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it solved my two questions - params.node.id indeed gives me the row Id, as well, now I can just create a new component which will have child components and then I free to pass them input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Andy. By console.log the parameter at agInit (params) I was able to find the row id: `params.node.id`

Comment: is there anyway to get this node.id in my component that uses `MyCustomCellRendererClass` ? i want to delete a row with this id but the id is only available in this component

Comment: thank you so much. this was the answer I am looking for a couple of hours @Menahem-gil